# Rails: how to write a test that ensures a couple of fields are hidden when toggled off but visible, and with correct values, when toggled on?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

How can I write a test that ensures a couple of fields are hidden when toggled off but visible when toggled on?

My current tests are passing where they shouldn't be. As you can see below, I've tried both have_field and xpath variations to test with Capybara. (Also tried have_css, no luck there either. I'm also trying to test for visibility, none of which seems to be tested for as the tests just keep on passing.)

I'm doing TDD, so need my test to fail before I make it pass, so I want to point out that the JavaScript isn't complete yet. When it's done it will need to adjust the time displayed in the 'End time' field to be the start time + 2 hours (@default_finish_time). At the moment it just displays the same time as the start time.

So the tests for whether the "End time" field displays @default_finish_time should be failing, but aren't. Anyone got any idea what's going on?

Would appreciate greatly, it's doing my head in at present.

```
        describe "toggling the 'Add finish time?' toggle on", :js => true do

            before {
                @default_finish_time = starts.change(:hour => 2)
                click_link "Add finish time?"               
            }

            # Tests to ensure that toggling this on, with only a start date entered, means the 
            # finish date field inherits whatever's in the start date field and the finish time
            # field inherits whatever's in the start time field + 2 hours (default event length).

            it { should have_css("#end_datetime_fields", 
                            visible: true) }

            it { should have_field("End dates", 
                            with: "#{starts.to_formatted_s(:formfield_date)}") }

            it { should have_field("End time", 
                            with: "#{starts.to_formatted_s(:formfield_time)}") }

            it { should have_field("End time", 
                            with: "#{@default_finish_time.to_formatted_s(:formfield_time)}", 
                            visible: true) }

            it { should have_xpath("//input[@value='#{starts.to_formatted_s(:formfield_time)}']") }

            it { should have_xpath("//input[@value='#{starts.change(:hour => 2).to_formatted_s(:formfield_time)}']") }
```

My view:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls span12">
        <%  # If JS is enabled, end date & time fields are hidden for progressive-disclosure 
            # purposes and we need a toggle to display them upon user request.
        %>
        <%= link_to("Add finish time?", {}, id: "specify_end_time") %>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group" id="end_datetime_fields">
    <div class="controls span2">
        <%= f.input :end_date_text, as: :string, 
                    :default => @event.end_date_text,
                    :input_html => { class: "date-field" },
                    :label => "End date" %>
    </div>
    <div class="controls span2">
        <%= f.input :end_time_text, as: :string, 
                    :default => @event.end_time_text,
                    :input_html => { class: "time-field" },
                    :label => "End time" %>
    </div>
    <div class="controls span2">
        <%= link_to("Remove finish time", {}, id: "remove_end_time") %>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my JavaScript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Hide end date/time fields by default and display them
    // only on user's request (when an end date or time need to be recorded).
    if ( $("#event_end_date_text").val == "" ) {
        $("#end_datetime_fields").hide();
    }

    $("#specify_end_time").click(function(){
        // Load up fields using data from start date/time fields (if filled out)
        $('#event_end_date_text').val(
            $('#event_start_date_text').val()
        );
        $('#event_end_time_text').val(
            // TODO: Add two hours to it before assigning the value to the field
            $('#event_start_time_text').val()
        );

        // Show fields (ie., show the container they're in)
        $("div#end_datetime_fields").show();

        // Hide toggle
        $("#specify_end_time").hide();

        return false;
    });


    $("#remove_end_time").click(function(){
        // Empty field contents
        $("#event_end_date_text").val("");
        $("#event_end_time_text").val("");

        // Hide fields (ie., hide the container they're in)
        $("div#end_datetime_fields").hide();

        // Show toggle
        $("#specify_end_time").show();

        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the changes are effected by Javascript, Capybara/RSpec aren't gonna be able to pick them up.

If you want to test Javascript logic you're gonna want to investigate something like Selenium or Jasime